# Swift 4 NSTableView action not called

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to get notified when a user clicks on a row of my `NSTableView` (MacOS), I tried with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.target = self
        tableView.action = #selector(self.onItemClicked)
    }

    @objc private func onItemClicked() {
        print("row \(tableView.clickedRow), col \(tableView.clickedColumn) clicked")
    }
```

I suppose it should be called on a click, but it isn't. 
 I'm using swift 4. 
Any advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: The built-in delegate method `tableViewSelectionDidChange` is not an option? By the way you can connect delegate and data source also in Interface Builder.

Comment: I would also go with the delegate, otherwise you can observe the `selectionDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: @vadian my problem was that had `tableView.isEnabled` set to `false` (by default maybe?). Setting to `true` had both mine and yours solution work, if you wish to create an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @nyg There is no need to *observe* explicitly, just implement `tableViewSelectionDidChange` as the delegate is set already.